# upload image to mysql in android studio

Tags: mysql

> 09-01 17:36:36.244 10323-10323/com.example.lar_pc.bottomnavdemo
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.lar_pc.bottomnavdemo, PID: 10323
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object
>   reference
>   at
>   com.example.lar_pc.bottomnavdemo.AlbumsFragment.onTaskCompleted(AlbumsFragment.java:103)
>   at
>   com.example.lar_pc.bottomnavdemo.MultiPartRequester$AsyncHttpRequest.onPostExecute(MultiPartRequester.java:119)
>   at
>   com.example.lar_pc.bottomnavdemo.MultiPartRequester$AsyncHttpRequest.onPostExecute(MultiPartRequester.java:52)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:674)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
>   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:691)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

Comment: @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(String response, int serviceCode) {
        AndyUtils.removeSimpleProgressDialog();
        Log.d("res", response.toString());
        //Log.d("res", response.toString());
        switch (serviceCode) {

            case CAMERA:
                if (parseContent.isSuccess(response)) {
                    String url = parseContent.getURL(response);
                    aQuery.id(imageview).image(url);
                }
        }
    }

Comment: Please add the code formatted to the question and not in the comments.